# Implementing simple transactions with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to implement a simple JMS Camel route that reads from a ActiveMQ Artemis queue. This route needs to be transacted to avoid message loss in case of application crashes or other unforeseen situations.

The problem is when I receive the message in my processor, and I call `exchange.isTransacted()` it returns `false`. I am expecting it to return `true`.

I am running a local broker for ActiveMQ Artemis on my machine. Below is my code:

**Main Class:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CamelTransactedJmsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelTransactedJmsMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Configuration Class:**

```java
@Configuration
public class TransactedJmsConfig {

    @Bean("activeMqTx")
    public JmsComponent activeMqTx() {
        JmsComponent activeMqTx = new JmsComponent();
        activeMqTx.setConfiguration(activeMqTxConfig());
        return activeMqTx;
    }

    @Bean("activeMqTxConfig")
    public JmsConfiguration activeMqTxConfig() {
        JmsConfiguration activeMqTxConfig = new JmsConfiguration();
        activeMqTxConfig.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        activeMqTxConfig.setTransactionManager(activeMqTransactionManager());
        activeMqTxConfig.setTransacted(true);
        activeMqTxConfig.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
        activeMqTxConfig.setDisableTimeToLive(true);
        return activeMqTxConfig;
    }

    @Bean("activeMqTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager activeMqTransactionManager() {
        JmsTransactionManager activeMqTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        activeMqTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        return activeMqTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean("cachingConnectionFactory")
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(activeMqConnectionFactory());
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean("activeMqConnectionFactory")
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return activeMqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW")
    public SpringTransactionPolicy PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW() {
        SpringTransactionPolicy PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
        PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW.setTransactionManager(activeMqTransactionManager());
        PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW");
        return PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW;
    }
}
```

**Route Class:**

```java
@Component
public class TransactedJmsRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activeMqTx:foo")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        System.out.println("isExchangeTransacted: " + exchange.isTransacted());
                        System.out.println(body);
                    }
                })
                .to("log:sample");

        from("timer:bar")
                .setBody(constant("Hello from Camel"))
                .to("activeMqTx:foo");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will answer your question (or at least help significantly).

Note that the JMS transaction manager will only be 'transactional' for connections provided by the connection factory.  This works fine if it is what you are after, but the use cases for this are limited.  You would be much better off (at least initially, perhaps) with a full up JTA transaction manager (such as Arjuna) installed as the `PlatformTransactionManager`

Your route will also need to be marked `transacted`.

Have a look at [transacted springboot example](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/blob/master/boot-bridge/src/main/resources/spring/camel-context.xml).  Note as well, there is a starter in the `pom.xml` file that installs Arjuna as the `PlatformTransactionManager`.  There is also `TRACE` level logging configured for Arjuna.  This will log transaction lifecycle events.